# How to set up two-weeks interval for datetime value

Tags: pandas, datetime, period

I am trying to lineup date values in my df to bi-weekly format.
Lets have 1st 2-weeks interval starts at 1/1/2021, the second interval starts at 1/14/2021
if df value belongs to 1st interval, i would like to see 1st interval value.

```
df = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=45)
df.to_period('2W').start_time
```

even if i set "2W" argument, it is one-week anyway.
but if I am using groupby function with "2W" - it works fine.
Can you please help me to find the solution?

My ANSWER:
I take week' number and converts to odd numbers. that gives me  chance to agreegate df by 2 weeks interval. Hope, it will help to someone :)

```
df['registered_2W'] = (lambda x: x+(x+1)%2)(df['registered'].dt.strftime("%V").astype(int))
```

Comment: Does this help: `df = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=45, freq='2W-FRI')` ?

Comment: .date_range - it is just an example to fill the df with values. Real df exists and i have to change existing datetime values.

Comment: Maybe hack your way in with `.dt.week/2`?  Then go back the other direction to get the date?  Ugly I know.  I don't see a good answer at this point.  Same problem you are having.

Comment: @jch - that was I am using as a solution: df['registered_2W'] = (lambda x: x+(x+1)%2)(df['registered'].dt.strftime("%V").astype(int))